# Track Source of Goal Link To Determine Single Post URL

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a link using [Googles Campaign URL builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) and used it in a Goal.

The same link is then added to every single post on my site.

This gives me the conversion data for each goal completion.

However i would like to find the data for each specific single post URL the link was clicked on?

What i need to know is which post they landed on when they clicked the link which resulted in a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this myself because i haven't received a decent answer.

To track the previous page URL for a link added to the goal funnel path.

In this example, the link i want to track before the destination URL is /register/ and the destination URL after sign up is /welcome-page/

The link which contains /register/ is exactly the same and has been added to thousands of pages.

What i want to report is which page URL the **/register/** link was clicked on before it resulted in a successful signup and a landing on the /welcome-page/ URL. This is called the **previous page path**.

Here's how to do it:

1. Go to Behavior > Site Content > All Pages
2. Add an advanced filter for '/register/'
3. Add a secondary dimension for 'Previous Page Path'

Here's what you'll see:

[image]

The green arrow shows the URL's for single posts/pages where the /register/ link was clicked which tells me which source URL's resulted in a successful goal.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use unique value of utm_content or utm_term for each link.

Comment: How do i do that if i'm using the same link on 2000 single posts?

Comment: I don't know how you technically was adding the links, but theoretically you can programatically take some word or part of URL of the page to make links unique.

Also, if the link with UTM leads to a different site rather than where it is set, you can add a secondary dimension to your report showing full referrer.

Comment: HTML only why do i need to do this? Does Google already know which URL the link was clicked on?